# CSS Dot above number

Tags: css, unicode

In Britain we describe recurring decimals as 1.3̇

In unicode

```
1.3&#775;
```

So far, so nice. However I am outputting my webpage to pdf and the application I am using does not play nice with these kind of combined diacritics. This annoying. Letters like Ȧ have their own unicode symbols, but digits don't.

However, I thought I could use CSS to put a little dot above the number (I'm using mpdf which has good CSS implementation).

However, I can find overline, but not any CSS code to simply place a dot above a number.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Solution 1

Using `<sup>` tag in html, we can se a superscript and it renders half a character above the normal line. The using css we can move that character to the desire position

> Solution2

We can surround the character inquestion my a `<p>` tag and add a class to it. The we can just style that class to achive the desire effect
The `display: inline` in the `<p>` tag its really important for this solution.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```css
sup {
  top: -3px;
  left: -2px;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
}

.unicode-hack {
  display: inline;
  top: -9px;
  left: -6px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h3>With code</h3>
<p>1.3&#775;</p>
<h3>Solution 1</h3>
<p>1.3<sup>.</sup></p>
<h3>Solution 2</h3>
<p>1.3</p>
<span class="unicode-hack">.</span>
```

Comment: semantically I would prefer `<p>1.3<span class="unicode-hack">.</span></p>` but it works

Comment: @happymacarts you have a good point. Edited to your comment. Thanks